# Why is html5 and flash fallover only going to flash once html is replaced replaced using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, flash, video

Hi I have want to change the src if a html5 video player using jquery and have come across a problem:

While the following changes the src:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.featureLogoText').click(function (e) {

                var media = $(this).attr('media');
                var mediamp4 = media + "mp4";
                var mediawebm = media + "webm";
                var mediaogv = media + "ogv";
                var newPoster = $(this).attr('data-poster');
                $('.scrPoster').attr('poster', newPoster);
                $('.scrVideomp4').attr('src', mediamp4);
                $('.scrVideowebm').attr('src', mediawebm);
                $('.scrVideogg').attr('src', mediaogv);
                $("#scrVideomp4").load();
                $("#scrVideowebm").load();
                $("#scrVideogg").load();
                $('.firstFrameFlash').attr('src', newPoster);

                //                $('embed').attr('flashparam', 'config={"playitem":[{"url":"http://localhost/test.flv","autoPlay":false}]}');

                $(".scrPoster > object > embed").attr("src", media + ".mp4");

            });
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="divVideoWrapper">
    <div class="divVideo">
        <div class="divVideoContainer">
            <div class="video_player">
                <video class="scrPoster" controls="controls" poster="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/images/frame3.png">
                    <source id="scrVideomp4" class="scrVideomp4" src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/video/bosch/testfeaturevideo.mp4"
                        type="video/mp4" />
                    <source id="scrVideowebm" class="scrVideowebm" src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/video/bosch/testfeaturevideo.webm"
                        type="video/webm" />
                    <source id="scrVideogg" class="scrVideogg" src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/video/bosch/testfeaturevideo.ogv"
                        type="video/ogg" />
                    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf"
                        width="352" height="198">
                        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
                        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                        <param class="flashparam" name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':['http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/images/frame3.png',{'url':'http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/video/bosch/testfeaturevideo.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}" />
                        <img class="firstFrameFlash" alt="Bosch Features" src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/images/frame3.png"
                            width="352" height="198" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
                    </object>
                </video>
                <div class="custom_controls">
                    <div class="divBigButton">
                        <a class="playBig" title="playBig"></a>
                    </div>
                    <a class="play" title="Play"></a><a class="pause" title="Pause"></a>
                    <div class="volumeWrapper">
                        <div class="volume">
                            <div class="volume_slider">
                            </div>
                            <a class="mute" title="Mute"></a><a class="unmute" title="Unmute"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timer">
                        00:00</div>
                    <div class="time_slider">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $('.video_player').myPlayer();
                });
            </script>
    </div>
```

When I click play on the video player it plays the old video not the new one.

I thought

```
 $("#scrVideomp4").load();
```

Would fix this but it doesn t seem to.

So On click i want it to stop the video that it playing and change it to the new one.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

As i am using html5 video and flash i tried removing the html in the videocontainer div and then replacing it with the new html as follows:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
        $('.featureLogoText').click(function (e) {
            var media = $(this).attr('media');
            var mediamp4 = media + "mp4";
            var mediawebm = media + "webm";
            var mediaogv = media + "ogv";
            var newPoster = $(this).attr('data-poster');

            var html = ' <video class=\"scrPoster\" controls=\"controls\" poster=\"' + newPoster + '\"><source id=\"scrVideomp4\" class=\"scrVideomp4\" src=\"' + mediamp4 + '\" type=\"video/mp4\" /><source id=\"scrVideowebm\" class=\"scrVideowebm\" src=\"' + mediawebm + '\" type=\"video/webm\" /><source id=\"scrVideogg\" class=\"scrVideogg\" src=\"' + mediaogv + '\" type=\"video/ogg\" /><object width=\"352\" height=\"198\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf\"></param><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"></param><param name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\"></param><embed src=\"http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" width=\"352\" height=\"198\" flashvars=\"src=' + mediamp4 + '&poster=' + newPoster + '\"></embed></object></video><div class=\"custom_controls\"><div class=\"divBigButton\"><a class=\"playBig\" title=\"playBig\"></a></div><a class=\"play\" title=\"Play\"></a><a class=\"pause\" title=\"Pause\"></a><div class=\"volumeWrapper\"><div class=\"volume\"><div class=\"volume_slider\"></div><a class=\"mute\" title=\"Mute\"></a><a class=\"unmute\" title=\"Unmute\"></a></div></div><div class=\"timer\">00:00</div><div class=\"time_slider\"></div></div>';
            alert(html);
            $("#videoPlayerChange").html("");
            $("#videoPlayerChange").append(html);

        });
    });
```

This work in the sense that the new video now plays but for some reason in chrome, firefox and ie9 rather than defaulting to the html5 player as it did before after the click it will be a flash player - why is this and is there a way round it? has it go something to do with the DOM already have been built or something along those lines?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found out why it was working:
So for the html5 video to update Iwas doing the .load on the source id rather than on the video so the following works:

```
                var media = $(this).attr('media');
                var mediamp4 = media + "mp4";
                var mediawebm = media + "webm";
                var mediaogv = media + "ogv";
                var newPoster = $(this).attr('data-poster');
                $('.scrPoster').attr('poster', newPoster);
                $('.scrVideomp4').attr('src', mediamp4);
                $('.scrVideowebm').attr('src', mediawebm);
                $('.scrVideogg').attr('src', mediaogv);
                $(".scrPoster").load();
```

and for flash i used the replace html:

```
  var html = ' <param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf\"></param><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"></param><param name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\"></param><embed src=\"http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" width=\"352\" height=\"198\" flashvars=\"src=' + mediamp4 + '&poster=' + newPoster + '\"></embed>';

                $("#objFlash").html("");
                $("#objFlash").append(html);
```

The html for the video player is as follows:

```
<div class="divVideoWrapper">
    <div class="divVideo">
        <div class="divVideoContainer">
            <div id="videoPlayerChange" class="video_player">
                <video class="scrPoster" controls="controls" poster="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/images/frame3.png">
                    <source id="scrVideomp4" class="scrVideomp4" src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/video/bosch/testfeaturevideo.mp4"
                        type="video/mp4" />
                    <source id="scrVideowebm" class="scrVideowebm" src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/video/bosch/testfeaturevideo.webm"
                        type="video/webm" />
                    <source id="scrVideogg" class="scrVideogg" src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/video/bosch/testfeaturevideo.ogv"
                        type="video/ogg" />
                    <object id="objFlash" width="352" height="198">
                        <param name="movie" value="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf">
                        </param>
                        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
                        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
                        <embed src="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                            allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="352" height="198" flashvars="src=http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/video/bosch/testfeaturevideo.mp4&poster=http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/images/frame3.png"></embed>
                        </object>

                </video>
                <div class="custom_controls">
                    <div class="divBigButton">
                        <a class="playBig" title="playBig"></a>
                    </div>
                    <a class="play" title="Play"></a><a class="pause" title="Pause"></a>
                    <div class="volumeWrapper">
                        <div class="volume">
                            <div class="volume_slider">
                            </div>
                            <a class="mute" title="Mute"></a><a class="unmute" title="Unmute"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timer">
                        00:00</div>
                    <div class="time_slider">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $('.video_player').myPlayer();
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tested this in ie8 and 9 Chrome and Firefox, the only thinkg that isn t wokring now is that even though ie9 uses the html5 player - it doesn t seem to recognise the poster attribute.  I hope this helps others.